# ReSharper highlights use of nameof with "Explicit argument passed to parameter with caller info attribute"

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, resharper-9.0, nameof

I'm using the nameof function to get a property name as a string thus:

```
public bool IsRunning => ...;

...
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsRunning));
```

ReSharper highlights this with the warning:

> Explicit argument passed to parameter with caller info attribute

The code works, I was just wondering if the above warning is something I should worry about.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> was just wondering if the above warning is something I should worry about.

When you have `CallerMemberName` attribute attached, you don't have to explicitly pass a value, because the attribute will do exactly that for you. It will find the caller's name and use it, making your `nameof` declaration redundant. This is of course assuming you call `RaisePropertyChanged` from the actual property implementation.

ReSharper marks these calls as redundant [when you explicitly pass a string literal](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/28/resharper-71-early-access-is-open/). It should force the same logic with `nameof` as well.

Comment: Ah I get it.  Hadn't quite appreciated what CallerMemberName was doing.The RaisePropertyChanged function (part of `ObservableObject` in `GalaSoft.MVVMLight`) was written before nameof existed, I guess it would be different if written now.

Comment: It's stupid because it doesn't check if name is different than current scope, so when I call explicitly to raise for another property it doesn't discover that.

Comment: I agree Shimmy and therefore it is better to be explicit in most cases just to avoid problems in your code

Comment: How do I disable this warning? Can you please post an example? I don't have Re#er, but I'm working on a repo that its owner has and cares about this complaint.

Comment: In a file, you can add at the top:
`// ReSharper disable ExplicitCallerInfoArgument`


And just once on the line above the call:
`// ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument`

Answer (score 4):

Not as long as your code is called from the `IsRunning` property (which makes the warning valid. Specifying the property name would be redundant in that case). It doesn't seem you are doing that.

The warning just tells you that the `RaisePropertyChanged` has the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` set on the property, which it should. It is safe to ignore.

Comment: Ah I see its nothing to do with nameof, its the RaisePropertyChanged that is being highlighted

Comment: No, I think you understand the use I guess. (If not sure, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31695900/993547)) You just raise the event it has changed. If it did, you are okay.