# Branch in C# Based on Boolean Pattern?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching, bitarray

Need to branch in C# (.NET 4.6.1) based on one of 16 different boolean patterns in an array (for readability in this message, 0==false and 1==true):

```
   0000
   0010
   0100
   0110
   0001
   0011
   0101
   0111
   1000
   1010
   1100
   1110
   1001
   1011
   1101
   1111
```

Not being concerned with overall performance at this time, what is a good way to make the branching human-readable for each of the 16 cases? Some of those that have "00" in the middle should behave the same, others not.

One idea is to convert each pattern to a String and then do a Switch or 16 "if" statements, not great. Each pattern is the significant portion of a BitArray, extracted and cast into a bool array.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question, but why not convert the bits into a number (e.g. a `byte`) and do a `switch` on that number?

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee, how do I convert 4 bools/bits to a byte?

Comment: Huh. I wrote that as an offhand comment assuming you'd get loads of answers. I'll compose an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(One way) to convert your four bools to a byte:

```
public byte BoolsToByte(IEnumerable<bool> bools)
{
    byte result = 0;
    foreach ( bool value in bools )
    {
        result *= 2;

        if ( value )
            result += 1;
    }

    return result;
}

public byte BoolsToByte(params bool[] bools)
{
    return BoolsToByte(bools.AsEnumerable());
}
```

where the overload gives you flexibility to call in one of two ways:

- `byte converted = BoolsToByte(bytes);`
- `byte converted = BoolsToByte(a, b, c, d);`

---

I haven't been able to get binary literals to work (using Visual Studio 2015, targeting .NET 4.6.1). Other C# 6.0 features like [`nameof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31695900/1364007) work, though. For now I'm reverting to 5.0 behaviour and leaving binary in as comments.

<strike>If you're compiling to .NET 4.6.1, I assume you're using C# 6.0 features such as [binary literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/594720/1364007) which will help with readability. In that case, you can use a syntax for the cases of your `switch` statement like this:</strike>

```
switch ( converted )
{
    case 0: // 0000
        // elided
        break;
    case 1: // 0001
    case 9: // 1001
        // elided
        break;

    // other cases elided

    case 15: // 1111
        // elided
        break;
}
```

Note I've combined 1 (`0001`) and 9 (`1001`) as an example because you said:

> Some of those that have "00" in the middle should behave the same, others not.

<strike>If you're not using C# 6.0 features, just replace the binary literals with the numeric equivalents from the comments.</strike>

Comment: I'm not accustomed to C# 6.0 (using 5.0 at the moment where I work) so this *seems* like the right syntax from what I read.

Comment: VS2015 is complaining about the binary literal usage. Still investigating.

Comment: Hmm - I just tried using binary literals myself - **definitely** had other C# 6.0 features such as `nameof`, but binary literals didn't work. Apologies for the confusion. I've modified my answer to not use binary literals.