# Is there an analog of nameof() from C# in Rust?

Tags: reflection, rust

In my program, I represent a history of changes to fields of some objects as follows:

```
struct FieldChange {
    property_name: &'static str,
    // some other fields
}

let history = Vec<FieldChange>::new();
```

I handle it like this:

```
match field_change.property_name {
    "name" => // do something,
    "age"  => // do something,
    _      => {}
}
```

To improve with readability and ease future refactoring, I would like to write something like this:

```
match field_change.property_name {
    nameof(Person::name) => // do something,
    nameof(Person::age)  => // do something,
    _                    => {}
}
```

where `nameof` generates a `&str` representation of the field, similar to [`nameof` in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695900/what-is-the-purpose-of-nameof).

The main point I'm looking for, is that the compiler can verify whether the fields exist (e.g., in this case, whether `Person` indeed has `name` and `age` fields). Is it possible to extract the field-names like this in Rust?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you can get something comparable with macros.  Because macros solve *everything!* <sup>[1]</sup>

```
macro_rules! name_of {
    ($name:ident in $ty:ty) => {
        {
            #[allow(dead_code)]
            fn dummy(v: $ty) {
                let _ = &v.$name;
            }
            stringify!($name)
        }
    };

    ($name:ident) => {
        {
            let _ = &$name;
            stringify!($name)
        }
    };
}

struct Person {
    // 255 years should be enough for anybody.
    age: u8,
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let p = Person { age: 27, name: "John Smith".into() };
    println!("The {} of Person {} is: {}", name_of!(age in Person), name_of!(p), p.age);
}
```

If you try to use a name that doesn't exist, you get something that looks like this:

```
error: unresolved name `q`. Did you mean `p`? [--explain E0425]
  --> <anon>:28:78
28 |>     println!("The {} of Person {} is: {}", name_of!(age in Person), name_of!(q), p.age);
   |>                                                                              ^
```

Or like this:

```
error: attempted access of field `shoe_size` on type `Person`, but no field with that name was found
 --> <anon>:6:26
6 |>                 let _ = &v.$name;
  |>                          ^
```

---

[1]: Note: macros do not, in fact, solve everything.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work with pattern matching. I assume, that procedural macros could help me when it comes

Comment: Ah, right; I forgot the `match` part.  There's nothing I can do about that: if you want to assert the name *exists*, you have to do something that uses it, and you can't do that within a pattern.  And no, procedural macros *will not* help, because they have the same limitations as regular macros here: *they cannot see names*.  They would *have* to emit something similar.