# How does nameof work?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I was just wondering how come nameof from C# 6,  can access non static property just like if it was static. Here is an example

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        string name = nameof(TestClass.Name); // whats so speciall about nameof
        //string name2 = TestClass.Name; this won't compile obviously, 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing special about it.  This happens at compile-time, not at runtime.  And the compiler has no problem whatsoever to convert a member named Name into a string literal "Name".  Only thing that's odd about it is why it took 6 versions to get added to the language :)

Comment: you may found your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695900/what-is-the-purpose-of-nameof

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not "accessing" the property - that operator is purely a compiler mechanism to inject the "name" of the argument into the code.  In this case it will replace `nameof(TestClass.Name)` with `"Name"`.  The fact that it's non-static is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, `nameof` can't access private members, your code does not work fine, it fails with: "CS0122 'A.Y' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Answer (score 8):

`nameof` Interpreter gets resolved at `compiletime` and translated to a `static string` instead.
In your case `nameof(TestClass.Name)` you will only return `"Name"` as a string.
You have to use `nameof(TestClass)`.
With `nameof` you can minimize redundancy in your code (For instance: you dont have to define a string for a propertyname or something like this by using `nameof`.

You can also use it to represent a classes name. But be aware! `nameof(MyClass)`
may not be the same as at runtime if you have an derived class! 
For runtime purposes use `typeOf` or `.GetType()` instead.

Read more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn986596.aspx)