# Golang get a string name of struct field

Tags: go, reflection

I would like to get the string name of a field like it is possible to do in C#:

```
if (x == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));
```

In GO I have the following:

```
package main

type Test struct{
    X int
    Y string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(nameof(Test.X))
}
```

How I can implement the `nameof` func?

Comment: May we know why you want this. I have the feeling this is an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: For a list of all useful cases on a different language see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695900/what-is-the-purpose-of-nameof . I know that is a different language but I am sure there could be some benefits.

Answer (score 3):

> How I can implement nameof func?

You cannot.

Fortunately you need not. While writing the code you know the name and can type the string literal as fast as `nameof()`.

(Okay, you technically can, by inspecting the current function an looking up debug symbols but this is *complicated* and probably non-portable and dependent on the compiler version used. So: Don't even try.)

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunally I need :) I need a dictinary with names of some fields, And if the field name is changed I would like to see the problem on the compile time.

Comment: @Alexander. No. You need to rethink the problem.

Comment: @Alexander You really should explain why you need this, so we can suggest an alternative. Whatever the implementation of `nameof()` would be, that will only run at runtime, so you can't get any compile time error out of it.

Comment: @icza 
Why you need something like this is because of easiness of refactoring. So you don't actually need it, but it makes it easier to refactor and prevent bugs that occur when you forget to rename some hard-coded strings you used for field names. 

Off course, you can cover this in a test, but discovering problems at compile time is just even better.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have this struct

```
type User struct{
    Id string
    Name string
    // etc
}
```

Then you can have something like this:

```
query :=  fmt.Sprintf("select * from Users where %s like %s", nameof(User.Name), "foo")
```

obviously in go the `nameof` function does not exists. You could replace that with `reflect.TypeOf(User.Name).Name()`

That is helpful because if you where to modify your database and replace Name with FirstName and LastName then your code will no longer compile.

Comment: does not build: `User.Name undefined (type User has no method Name)`

Comment: Read the entire answer. I am saying that the name of that funtion does not exist and was showing an example of how you use it in different languages like on c#.

Comment: `reflect.TypeOf(User.Name).Name()` is in Go, and does not compile